# Installing modules reliably in one location

Tags: python, module, installation, pythonpath

I've been working with Python for a little while now but have come to absolutely detest installing new modules. It always seems to take me a full work day to install one additional module. This last happened with `mpl_toolkits` and now it is happening with `gdal`.

The main issue seems to be that `easy_install`/`pip`/`get-app` aren't saving a file in the correct location and so Python (I'm using Spyder) can't find it. How do I install a module in a location so that Python can find it?

I have been reading guides, articles, manuals and Stack Overflow articles all day now and I feel this needs a new question as I can't find an answer.

- It is installing fine, it's just Python (and I) can't find it
- It's not in the `/lib/python2.7/site-packages` folder, which seems to be the Python default, although half the modules that do work aren't in there when I list it

I installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```

I also tried with:

```
pip install gdal
```

but this fails with the error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with the error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-NWJT2f/gdal/
```

I looked for the files using

```
dpkg -L gdal
```

and then added the file path this said into Spyder's preferences option for `PYTHONPATH`, but it still couldn't find it and so I'm guessing this is wrong.

I have read [the official documentation of `PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html), but it's very short and doesn't really explain it at all.

Comment: Your question is too broad (at least according to question title). If you want to resolve installation of gdal, focus on that. There are working solutions for that. Anyway, you shall be familiar with things like `pip`, and `virtualenv` to get any further.

Comment: For gdal, better use `pygdal`. Read documentation for it first, it will advice you to install exactly the version matching `gdal` installed in the system.

Comment: Hey @JanVlcinsky The question is vague because I always have this issue - it isn't an issue specifically with gdal. It's with the method I have been using to install packages - as Python can regularly not find them. The title got edited after I posted it, from "Installing modules reliably in one location for Python" to remove the "in Python".  And someone else commented about using Anaconda to install packages (conda install command), which has solved the issue. Again, yeah I simply needed someone to point me to a different way of installing that just worked more reliably - conda apparently

Comment: Good you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend trying anaconda or miniconda, which manage environments and install packages - it 'just works'.

https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: Hey User1293213: I did my original install using anaconda 2 as I am using Spyder as the interface for Python. Thanks - Think I've found what you were referring to: conda install gdal